# Reference columns in dataframes throwing ambiguous error when joining two dataframes where one dataframe has an array of reference keys

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes as follows

dataframeOne

```
+--------------------------------------------
|______subject_______________|______marks___|
| Maths                      |    89        |
| English                    |    90        |
| Religion                   |    80        |
---------------------------------------------
```

dataframeTwo

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------
|______name__________________|______subject__________________|
| Liza                       |   [Maths]                     |
| Inter                      |   [Religion, English]         |
| Ovin                       |   [Maths, Religion, English]  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected output

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------
|______name__________________|______marks____________________|
| Liza                       |   [89]                        |
| Inter                      |   [80, 90]                    |
| Religion                   |   [89, 80, 90]                |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

To get the above output I need to join dataframeOne and DataframeTwo. But in dataframeTwo subject Column is having arrays while dataframe one is having a string value. I tried the below code with the error followed by

```
val newDataframe = dataframeTwo.withColumn("myMarks", struct('marks))
    val studentMarksDataframe = dataframeOne.join(newDataframe, array_contains(subject, subject)).agg(collect_list('myMarks))
```

Error

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
> Reference 'unicode' is ambiguous, could be: subject, subject

How can I solve the above issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two Coomon columns throwing ambiguous error when joining two dataframes where one dataframe has an array of reference keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66768749/two-coomon-columns-throwing-ambiguous-error-when-joining-two-dataframes-where-on)

Comment: It's your own earlier closed post of this question closed as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59534351/3404097), if you think it isn't then please edit it to improve per the [help], don't repost, it's closed for a reason.

Comment: @philipxy this question is different from the deleted one (before it was edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
val studentMarksDataframe = dataframeOne.join(
    dataframeTwo, 
    array_contains(dataframeTwo("subject"), dataframeOne("subject"))
).groupBy("name").agg(collect_list('marks))
```

Comment: im getting the following error Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;;

Comment: @tharindu ... that looks like an unrelated error, probably about streaming. I'm afraid I can't help on that

Comment: ok. because one of my dataframes is a stream dataframe. anyway thanks for the answer